# Issue with translating a delegate function from c# to vb.net for use with Google OAuth 2

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-3.5, delegates, anonymous-function

I've been trying to translate a Google OAuth 2 example from C# to Vb.net for a co-worker's project. 
I'm having on end of issues translating the following methods:

```
    private OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient> CreateAuthenticator()
        {
            // Register the authenticator.
            var provider = new WebServerClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
            provider.ClientIdentifier = ClientCredentials.ClientID;
            provider.ClientSecret = ClientCredentials.ClientSecret;
            var authenticator = 
                new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(provider, GetAuthorization) { NoCaching = true };
            return authenticator;
        }

        private IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(WebServerClient client)
        {
            // If this user is already authenticated, then just return the auth state.
            IAuthorizationState state = AuthState;
            if (state != null)
            {
                return state;
            }

            // Check if an authorization request already is in progress.
            state = client.ProcessUserAuthorization(new HttpRequestInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request));
            if (state != null && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.AccessToken) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.RefreshToken)))
            {
                // Store and return the credentials.
                HttpContext.Current.Session["AUTH_STATE"] = _state = state;
                return state;
            }

            // Otherwise do a new authorization request.
            string scope = TasksService.Scopes.TasksReadonly.GetStringValue();
            OutgoingWebResponse response = client.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(new[] { scope });
            response.Send(); // Will throw a ThreadAbortException to prevent sending another response.
            return null;
        }
```

The main issue being this line:

```
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(provider, GetAuthorization) { NoCaching = true };
```

The Method signature reads as for this particular line reads as follows:

```
Public Sub New(tokenProvider As TClient, authProvider As System.Func(Of TClient, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState))
```

My understanding of Delegate functions in VB.net isn't the greatest. However I have read over all of the MSDN documentation and other relevant resources on the web, but I'm still stuck as to how to translate this particular line.

So far all of my attempts have resulted in either the a cast error (see below) or no call to GetAuthorization.

**The Code (vb.net on .net 3.5)**

```
    Private Function CreateAuthenticator() As OAuth2Authenticator(Of WebServerClient)
        ' Register the authenticator.
        ' Register the authenticator.
        Dim provider = New WebServerClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, oauth.ClientID, oauth.ClientSecret)

        'GetAuthorization isn't called
        'Dim authenticator = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of WebServerClient)(provider, AddressOf GetAuthorization) With {.NoCaching = True}

        'This works, but results in type error
        Dim authDelegate As Func(Of WebServerClient, IAuthorizationState) = AddressOf GetAuthorization
        Dim authenticator = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of WebServerClient)(provider, authDelegate) With {.NoCaching = True}

        'This works, but results in type error
        'Dim authenticator = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of WebServerClient)(provider, GetAuthorization(provider)) With {.NoCaching = True}

        'GetAuthorization isn't called
        'Dim authenticator = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of WebServerClient)(provider, New Func(Of WebServerClient, IAuthorizationState)(Function(c) GetAuthorization(c))) With {.NoCaching = True}
        'Dim authenticator = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of WebServerClient)(provider, New Func(Of WebServerClient, IAuthorizationState)(AddressOf GetAuthorization)) With {.NoCaching = True}

        Return authenticator
    End Function



    Private Function GetAuthorization(arg As WebServerClient) As IAuthorizationState
        ' If this user is already authenticated, then just return the auth state.
        Dim state As IAuthorizationState = AuthState

        If (Not state Is Nothing) Then
            Return state
        End If

        ' Check if an authorization request already is in progress.
        state = arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(New HttpRequestInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request))
        If (state IsNot Nothing) Then
            If ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(state.AccessToken) = False Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(state.RefreshToken) = False)) Then
                ' Store Credentials
                HttpContext.Current.Session("AUTH_STATE") = state
                _state = state

                Return state
            End If
        End If

        ' Otherwise do a new authorization request.
        Dim scope As String = AnalyticsService.Scopes.AnalyticsReadonly.GetStringValue()
        Dim _response As OutgoingWebResponse = arg.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(New String() {scope})
        ' Add Offline Access and forced Approval
        _response.Headers("location") += "&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force"
        _response.Send() ' Will throw a ThreadAbortException to prevent sending another response.

        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

**The Cast Error**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Unable to cast object of type 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationState' to type 'System.Func`2[DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient,DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState]'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationState' to type 'System.Func`2[DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient,DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState]'.
```

I've spent the better part of a day on this, and it's starting to drive me nuts. 
Help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I'm failed to mention that I have tried all of the available online C# to VB.net code converts. All result in the following conversion of the line in question:

```
Dim authenticator = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of WebServerClient)(provider, AddressOf GetAuthorization) With {.NoCaching = True}
```

Which results in the GetAuthorization method not being called.

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue, because i am facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code that the converter came up with, as well as your other solutions that don't throw exceptions, all look fine. If there were problems with converting that line code, an exception or error would appear. That would mean the problem lies elsewhere in the code, possibly in the `OAuth2Authenticator(T)` constructor.

Would it be possible for your co-worker to simply use a reference to the library (either binary or project) so you won't have to convert the code?

Answer (score 0):

For translating code from one language to another try to use great tool, SharpDevelop. This tool is freeware alternative to MS VS 2008 and you can translate between C#, VB.NET, IronPython and Boo languages

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I've tried all of the c# to vb.net code converts. They all come back with: Dim authenticator = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of WebServerClient)(provider, AddressOf GetAuthorization) With {.NoCaching = True}, which results in the GetAuthorization method not being called.